# How can I get a list of pages that contain one or more keyword - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to SQL and I was hoping someone could help me in finding a query to implement the following function:

I have two database tables. One is called **page** and is a list of pages on my website. The other table is called **keywords** and contains keywords and the corresponding pages on which they can be found.

The table structure is as follows

```
Page                       Keywords
+-------+------+           +-------+-------+
| Pg_ID | URL  |           | Word  | Pg_ID |
+-------+------+           +-------+-------+
```

For example the following entries can be found in the keywords table:

- word1 - page1
- word1 - page2
- word2 - page1
- word2 - page2
- word3 - page3

I get a query from a search box and split it into keywords.

For example, the keywords from the search query are: word1, word2

How can I return a list of pages that contain these keywords, which in this example would be page1, page2?

Can someone please explain how I can create an SQL query to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: pls provide table structure

Comment: Please [read how to get the relevant information](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/guide-how-to-add-database-details-to-your-question) and file an [edit].

Comment: For starters, we need to see some code of what you have tried to actually help you troubleshoot this problem.  Secondly, have you considered storing the relevant information in your database and using the [FULLTEXT search features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) available in MySQL?

Comment: Where keyword in ('x','y') group by pageid having count([distinct] keyword) = 2

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand what you have setup, [With the Following SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2521d4/1) I believe I've got what you need done. without column names I just assumed and made some up.

### SQL Data

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
  page_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  page_keyword VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO pages VALUES (1,'cool'),
  (1,'awesome'),
  (2,'lame'),
  (2,'waffle'),
  (3,'holy'),
  (3,'pope'),
  (3,'waffle');
```

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_keyword = 'waffle';
```

### Data Received

```
PAGE_ID       PAGE_KEYWORD
2              waffle
3              waffle
```

Comment: this may not be the answer, but it does at least demonstrate how to ask the question